# Handle Webpack 5's Polyfill issues in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, webpack, cosm

I am trying to use cosmjs' packages in Ionic Vue. When I would like to import

```
import { DirectSecp256k1HdWallet } from "@cosmjs/proto-signing";
```

I received this problem:

```
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }
```

and unable to use the application in the app.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/quickstart#prefetching-application-javascript) and [Vue](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) docs you can easily merge a custom object into the final webpack config.

First of all, install the browser version of your crypto module by executing:

`npm install crypto-browserify`

Then you should create a `vue.config.js` file in your project root like this:

```js
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            fallback: {
                crypto: require.resolve( 'crypto-browserify' )
                // Any other missed node module
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You should be able to repeat this process for every missed node native module that has a browser version.